# Can I touch resistor connected to mains power?

Tags: resistors, ac, mains

Can I touch resistor connected to mains power?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffb2w6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can we ask why you're asking?

Comment: Because LED working when connected with resistor to 220VAC, so i think the volt and amp after resistor is very small and safe to touch, but i want make sure.

Comment: Hint: one side of the AC line may be connected to ground. You might be standing on the ground, leaning on a grounded surface, etc.

Comment: @amy  Why do you want to touch it?

Comment: Can i touch "live" wire after resistor?

Comment: @amy, please answer my question.

Comment: Remember, the LED only conducts in one direction, so half of every cycle the point you're touching will be well above the forward voltage of the LED. That is assuming you don't kill the LED from reverse breakdown.

Comment: I can touch "Screwdriver Test", "Screwdriver Test" have lamp + resistor

Comment: There are ways to safely do this, but if you wish to perform such an experiment you should do so with the assistance of a professional.  If it's a purely theoretical question the answer could be a bit different, but 220vRMS is 311vPeak, and a tremendous amount of caution is merited.

Comment: @amyprogrammer No this circuit is not safe to touch. If the + wire is phase, then it is *safeish*, but you do not know this. If the - wire turns out to be phase, then you are directly grabbing phase. You never should assume that any power point / lead / house has been wired correctly. Phase and neutral swapped is a common occurrence (in the real world).

Comment: Are you asking the internet for permission to do something dangerous?

Comment: The "mains tester screwdrivers" are designed to be safe...ish... but many people still wouldn't trust them.

Comment: what is the value of "mains tester screwdrivers" resistor ? or it's not resistor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can.

Of course, a certain percentage of the times you do that you will die, but that's not what you asked.

Your circuit, as shown, is guaranteed to kill the LED, since on the negative halves of the power cycle as much as 310 volts will appear across the LED and destroy it. If you are lucky, the LED will fail short, and this will protect you. Murphy's Law ("Anything which can go wrong, will.") suggests that the LED will instead fail open, so touching your point will apply 220 volts to you. Of course, the 100k resistor will limit that current, but the result will still not be good.

As KH has answered, at your stage of knowledge, you should make an ironclad rule NEVER to deal with mains voltages directly. You simply don't know enough to deal with the hazards in a safe manner. Know your limitations.

Comment: If it fails short, than depending on the way that the mains is connected, he might be directly connected to the hot terminal, and the resistor wont do anything

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this.  It takes quite a bit of training to begin to predict what *could* happen in a case like this.  There are safe ways to perform numerous electrical experiments, including energizing oneself, but these experiments should be performed by professionals who understand the risks.

With 120VAC current, even 50-100mA is "about right" to stop the human heart, and that is far below the amount that will lock up your muscles, burn or vaporize you.

Do not risk your life.  If you are interested in electricity, start learning about it.  Even the very basics will go a long way towards knowing how to protect yourself.